# Defining event on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview

Forgive me for being rather new (that would be very new) to iOS development.

I have just implemented native Facebook authorization, and now I want to pass my access_token to a local html file in a UIWebView. For that sake, I have created a Javascript object in the html file, with an init function that receives the access_token as parameter. Now I just need to externally call that function. Some research got me to `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)]` - but this should not be called until the page has been loaded.

In my `ViewController.m` I have defined a `- (void)updateView` in which I do a request on `webView` which is a `UIWebView`. I would now like to execute a JavaScript string as soon as this particular requests completes. How do I do that?

```
- (void)updateView {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mydomainwuhuu/mobile?o=Auth&accessToken=%@", appDelegate.session.accessToken]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert('test')"];
    }
}
```

This code doesn't do it, and I think it's because I call the JavaScript before the page is finished loading? How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView has delegate methods see [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).For your situation make use of `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` .

Comment: How? Right now I have something like:

`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thisWebView {[thisWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"wuff.init()"];
}`

But it does not execute the function..

Comment: add a alert inside that function.Can you paste the JS function code

Comment: I included a window.alert("test") inside the wuff.init() function. The problem is not with the JavaScript. If I open the html file in my web browser and execute wuff.init() the popup is shown..

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load) .Try to achieve using JS.

Comment: That is not an option because I need the variable delivered from AppDelegate. See the code I posted on Pastebin in previous comment :)

Comment: Try passing a plain text inside `wuff.init()`.Example `wuff.init('test')` .If its working fine then you need to find solution for how to pass a escaped string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24783/discussion-between-caspar-aleksander-bang-jespers-and-kaar3k)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before. I only ended up including a "Done" button and including the stringbyevaluatingjavascript function inside the IBAction button call.

It worked then.

Comment: I'm not interested in doing so. It has to happen automatically when loaded.